# Is there a way to have a url instead of a document in a library

Tags: url, library

Other then using a webpart in the library page or adding a URL column, is there a way to have a url stored in a SP Library instead of a document?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the link to document content type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add a **Link to a Document** content type

1. Library settings -> Advanced settings -> Set "Allow management of content types?" to "Yes"
2. Under content Types group, click "Add from existing site content types". Search for "**Link to a Document**" content type and add it to the Library

[image]